# Factorial using recursion but getting the values in some order

Tags: c

**Following code which has the output of 5 and How to modify the code to get the actual output by return ??**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fact(int ,int ,int);
int main(void)
{
    int a=5;
    int b=a;
    int i=1;
    printf("%d",fact(a,i,b));
}
int fact(int a,int i,int b)
{
   if(i<b)
    {
        a=a*i;
        i++;
        fact(a,i,b);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question **please**?

Comment: And while you rephrase the question avoid the word "stack". There is no stack in your code.

Comment: @axiac The original poster is perhaps referring to the call stack.

Comment: @Codor I know what he mean.

Comment: I have modified the code and it's printing the value as 5 instead of 120.May I know why ???

Answer (score 0):

The signature of your implementation does not permit to return a result. You could change your implementation to the following.

```
int fact(int a) 
{
    int Result;
    if (0 == a)
        Result = 1;
    else
        Result = a * fact(a-1);
    return Result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forgot to `return` from `fact` function from `if` condition?

```
void fact(int a,int i,int b) 
{     
if(i<b)    
  {     
    a=a*i;       
    i++;        
    fact(a,i,b);  
    return;                  //<-- Added code
  }     
  printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the stack:

`1*f(0)=1
|
|
4*f(3)
5*f(4)
f(5)`

`so,while getting poped from stack:
1*2*3*4*5=120.`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=5;
    int ans=f(a);
    printf("%d\n",ans);
    return 0;

}
int f(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return (n*f(n-1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct answer to my problem and in this case i need to write two return statements to throw the value to the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fact(int ,int ,int);
int main(void)
{
    int a=5;
    int b=a;
    int i=1;
    printf("%d",fact(a,i,b));
}
int fact(int a,int i,int b)
{
   if(i<b)
    {
        a=a*i;
        i++;
        fact(a,i,b);
        return;
    }
    return a;
}
```